# ERROR forceExpand: error parsing data soruce document for element jsonObject in WSO2 EI 6.1.1

Tags: json, salesforce, payload, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am pushing Lead Details to Salesforce in WSO2 EI. after getting response from Salesforce,facing exception like **"forceExpand: error parsing data soruce document for element jsonObject"** in aggregation part. Can anyone help me to resolve this?

**EI Version:** 6.1.1

**Request:**

```
    {
   "getLead":{
      "Company":"N/A",
      "Email":"mlowery2035@gmail.com",
      "FirstName":"Marie",
      "PostalCode":"4214",
      "Contact__c":"0035500000hcGjcAAE",
      "MobilePhone":"+61 410 418 784",
      "Model_Name_Text__c":"D90",
      "Selling_Dealer__c":"Ferry Rd LDV",
      "Lead_Type__c":"Internet",
      "LeadSource":"OEM",
      "Interest_of_Make_Text__c":"LDV",
      "Account__c":"0015500000kkXt7AAE",
      "LastName":"Lowery",
      "Location__c":"Ferry Rd",
      "Department__c":"LDV"
   }
}
```

**Response:**

```
"{\"transactionId\":null,\"timestamp\":\"2020-05-12 18:55:41\",\"OpportunityId\":\"0065500000GBt0NAAT\",\"message\":\"Insert/Update success\",\"Le
ad\":{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"Lead\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Lead/00Q5500000AyPLGEA3\"},\"Company\":\"N/A\",\"Email\":\"mlowery2035@gmail.com\",\"FirstName\":\"M
arie\",\"PostalCode\":\"4214\",\"Contact__c\":\"0035500000hcGjcAAE\",\"MobilePhone\":\"+61 410 418 784\",\"Model_Name_Text__c\":\"D90\",\"Interest_Of_Model__c\":\"a0455000009TzvQAA
S\",\"Selling_Dealer__c\":\"Ferry Rd LDV\",\"Lead_Type__c\":\"Internet\",\"LeadSource\":\"OEM\",\"Interest_of_Make_Text__c\":\"LDV\",\"Account__c\":\"0015500000kkXt7AAE\",\"LastNam
e\":\"Lowery\",\"Location__c\":\"Ferry Rd\",\"Id\":\"00Q5500000AyPLGEA3\",\"Department__c\":\"LDV\"},\"errorCode\":\"200\",\"appraisalId\":null}"
```

CODE:

```
 <iterate expression="//jsonArray/jsonElement" id="LDVid" sequential="true">
                            <target>
                                <sequence>
<!--In this sequence pushed above request to Salesforce -->
                                    <sequence description="VBEmail_LDVNonQualifiedLead_Sequence" key="VBEmail_LDVNonQualifiedLead_Sequence"/>
                                </sequence>
                            </target>
                        </iterate>
                        <property name="Aggregated_Responses" scope="default">
                            <jsonObject/>
                        </property>
                        <aggregate id="LDVid">
                            <completeCondition>
                                <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
                            </completeCondition>
                            <onComplete enclosingElementProperty="Aggregated_Responses" expression="$body/*[1]" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd">
                                <log description="***aggregated***" separator="***aggregated***">
                                    <property expression="$body/*[1]" name="===Aggregated SF Resonse=="/>
                                </log>
                            </onComplete>
                        </aggregate>
```

**axis2 - message Formatter:**

```
<messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
                         class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/>
```

**Wire Logs:**

```
[2020-05-12 16:17:24,441] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "Vary: Accept-Encoding[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:24,441] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:24,442] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:24,442] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:24,442] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:24,443] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "Host: vonbibra--vbdevmerge.my.salesforce.com[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:24,443] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:24,443] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:24,443] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:24,444] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "198[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:24,444] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "{"getLead":{"Company":"N/A","Email":"mlowery2035@gmail.com","FirstName":"Marie","PostalCode":"4214","Con
tact__c":"0035500000hcGjcAAE","MobilePhone":"+61 410 418 784","Model_Name_Text__c":"D90","Selling_Dealer__c":"Ferry Rd LDV","Lead_Type__c":"Internet","LeadSource":"OEM","Interest_o
f_Make_Text__c":"LDV","Account__c":"0015500000kkXt7AAE","LastName":"Lowery","Location__c":"Ferry Rd","Department__c":"LDV"}}[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:24,444] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "0[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:24,445] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 << "[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:29,001] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:29,001] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Date: Tue, 12 May 2020 10:47:24 GMT[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:29,001] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536002; includeSubDomains[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:29,001] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Public-Key-Pins-Report-Only: pin-sha256="9n0izTnSRF+W4W4JTq51avSXkWhQB8duS2bxVLfzXsY="; pin-sha256="5kJv
NEMw0KjrCAu7eXY5HZdvyCS13BbA0VJG1RSP91w="; pin-sha256="njN4rRG+22dNXAi+yb8e3UMypgzPUPHlv4+foULwl1g="; max-age=86400; includeSubDomains; report-uri="https://a.forcesslreports.com/hp
kp-report/00D550000000fgkm";[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:29,002] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Expect-CT: max-age=86400, report-uri="https://a.forcesslreports.com/Expect-CT-report/00D550000000fgkm"[\
r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:29,002] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:29,003] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:29,003] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "X-Robots-Tag: none[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:29,003] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Cache-Control: no-cache,must-revalidate,max-age=0,no-store,private[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:29,003] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Set-Cookie: BrowserId=9yk0npQ9EeqWJksZmFqNqg; domain=.salesforce.com; path=/; expires=Wed, 12-May-2021 1
0:47:24 GMT; Max-Age=31536000[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:29,004] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:29,004] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Vary: Accept-Encoding[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:29,004] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:29,005] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:29,005] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "33F[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:29,006] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> ""{\"transactionId\":null,\"timestamp\":\"2020-05-12 20:47:28\",\"OpportunityId\":\"0065500000GBuJsAAL\",
\"message\":\"Insert/Update success\",\"Lead\":{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"Lead\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Lead/00Q5500000AyPQoEAN\"},\"Company\":\"N/A\",\"Email\":\
"mlowery2035@gmail.com\",\"FirstName\":\"Marie\",\"PostalCode\":\"4214\",\"Contact__c\":\"0035500000hcGjcAAE\",\"MobilePhone\":\"+61 410 418 784\",\"Model_Name_Text__c\":\"D90\",\"
Interest_Of_Model__c\":\"a0455000009TzvQAAS\",\"Selling_Dealer__c\":\"Ferry Rd LDV\",\"Lead_Type__c\":\"Internet\",\"LeadSource\":\"OEM\",\"Interest_of_Make_Text__c\":\"LDV\",\"Acc
ount__c\":\"0015500000kkXt7AAE\",\"LastName\":\"Lowery\",\"Location__c\":\"Ferry Rd\",\"Id\":\"00Q5500000AyPQoEAN\",\"Department__c\":\"LDV\"},\"errorCode\":\"200\",\"appraisalId\"
:null}""
[2020-05-12 16:17:29,057] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:29,058] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "0[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:29,058] [] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 >> "[\r][\n]"
[2020-05-12 16:17:29,059] []  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:57e0eec8-fbe3-428a-a127-44291f2a1
aa3, Direction: request, Payload: "{\"transactionId\":null,\"timestamp\":\"2020-05-12 20:47:28\",\"OpportunityId\":\"0065500000GBuJsAAL\",\"message\":\"Insert/Update success\",\"Le
ad\":{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"Lead\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Lead/00Q5500000AyPQoEAN\"},\"Company\":\"N/A\",\"Email\":\"mlowery2035@gmail.com\",\"FirstName\":\"M
arie\",\"PostalCode\":\"4214\",\"Contact__c\":\"0035500000hcGjcAAE\",\"MobilePhone\":\"+61 410 418 784\",\"Model_Name_Text__c\":\"D90\",\"Interest_Of_Model__c\":\"a0455000009TzvQAA
S\",\"Selling_Dealer__c\":\"Ferry Rd LDV\",\"Lead_Type__c\":\"Internet\",\"LeadSource\":\"OEM\",\"Interest_of_Make_Text__c\":\"LDV\",\"Account__c\":\"0015500000kkXt7AAE\",\"LastNam
e\":\"Lowery\",\"Location__c\":\"Ferry Rd\",\"Id\":\"00Q5500000AyPQoEAN\",\"Department__c\":\"LDV\"},\"errorCode\":\"200\",\"appraisalId\":null}"
[2020-05-12 16:17:29,064] [] ERROR - OMSourcedElementImpl forceExpand: error parsing data soruce document for element jsonObject
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Not in an object
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.hasNext(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:449)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.next(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:456)
        at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.next(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.forceExpand(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:264)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.getFirstOMChild(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:867)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.OMNavigator._getFirstChild(OMNavigator.java:196)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.OMNavigator.updateNextNode(OMNavigator.java:140)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.OMNavigator.getNext(OMNavigator.java:112)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.SwitchingWrapper.updateNextNode(SwitchingWrapper.java:1113)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.SwitchingWrapper.<init>(SwitchingWrapper.java:235)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.OMStAXWrapper.<init>(OMStAXWrapper.java:74)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMStAXWrapper.<init>(OMStAXWrapper.java:52)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMContainerHelper.getXMLStreamReader(OMContainerHelper.java:51)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getXMLStreamReader(OMElementImpl.java:736)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.cloneOMElement(OMElementImpl.java:1038)
        at org.apache.synapse.util.MessageHelper.cloneSOAPEnvelope(MessageHelper.java:690)
        at org.apache.synapse.util.MessageHelper.cloneAxis2MessageContextForAggregate(MessageHelper.java:471)
        at org.apache.synapse.util.MessageHelper.cloneMessageContextForAggregateMediator(MessageHelper.java:219)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.aggregator.AggregateMediator.getAggregatedMessage(AggregateMediator.java:522)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.aggregator.AggregateMediator.completeAggregate(AggregateMediator.java:456)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.aggregator.AggregateMediator.mediate(AggregateMediator.java:337)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.SwitchMediator.mediate(SwitchMediator.java:193)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:267)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:775)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:282)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:554)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:188)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:262)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2020-05-12 16:17:29,081] [] ERROR - AnonymousListMediator Error parsing data source document:Not in an object
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing data source document:Not in an object
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.forceExpand(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:269)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.getFirstOMChild(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:867)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.OMNavigator._getFirstChild(OMNavigator.java:196)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.OMNavigator.updateNextNode(OMNavigator.java:140)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.OMNavigator.getNext(OMNavigator.java:112)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.SwitchingWrapper.updateNextNode(SwitchingWrapper.java:1113)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.SwitchingWrapper.<init>(SwitchingWrapper.java:235)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.OMStAXWrapper.<init>(OMStAXWrapper.java:74)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMStAXWrapper.<init>(OMStAXWrapper.java:52)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMContainerHelper.getXMLStreamReader(OMContainerHelper.java:51)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getXMLStreamReader(OMElementImpl.java:736)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.cloneOMElement(OMElementImpl.java:1038)
        at org.apache.synapse.util.MessageHelper.cloneSOAPEnvelope(MessageHelper.java:690)
        at org.apache.synapse.util.MessageHelper.cloneAxis2MessageContextForAggregate(MessageHelper.java:471)
        at org.apache.synapse.util.MessageHelper.cloneMessageContextForAggregateMediator(MessageHelper.java:219)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.aggregator.AggregateMediator.getAggregatedMessage(AggregateMediator.java:522)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.aggregator.AggregateMediator.completeAggregate(AggregateMediator.java:456)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.aggregator.AggregateMediator.mediate(AggregateMediator.java:337)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.SwitchMediator.mediate(SwitchMediator.java:193)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:267)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:775)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:282)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:554)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:188)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:262)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Not in an object
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.hasNext(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:449)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.next(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:456)
        at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.next(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.forceExpand(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:264)
        ... 30 more
```

**Note**: Tried the same request in soql workbench(Rest Explorer option) which push records to Salesforce successfully.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but according to the documentation https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/JSON+Support the meesageFormatter class should be org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamFormatter. Can you change your config and try again?

Comment: Hi @MartinHald
Thanks for ur reply. the mentioned JSON Formatter is available in default manner of wso2 axis2 file, that is not working, so that i changed that into new JSON MessageFormatter.